# How can I make user's input work on different methods in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

How could I make team1 in method1 work in method 2?

```
static void method1()
{
  string team1 = "";
  team1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
static void method2()
{

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Pls have  look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How/when is method1 and method2 called?

Comment: Is the question [how to pass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods#passing-parameters) `team1` value into `method2()`?

Comment: You probably want a field, and in addition, those methods and that field not being static.

Comment: You can pass data in multiple ways. But without the details in your question, it is hard for us to determine what exactly you need. Add some information on what is the expectation, what did you try and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want.

You could either pass the variable to `method2`:

```
void method1()
{
  string team1 = "";
  team1 = Console.ReadLine();
  method2(team1);
}
void method2(string team)
{
  // do things with (any) team)
}
```

or you could use a property, accessible by `method2`:

```
public string Team1 {get; set; } // properties start with upper letter
void method1()
{
  Team1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
void method2()
{
  // Team1 is accessible here
}
```

And to complete the answer, use a field:

```
string _team1;
void method1()
{
  _team1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
void method2()
{
  // _team1 is accessible here
}
```

Btw: I removed `static`, since it's mostly not what you want/need.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you, updated the post. Finger faster then brain, it's friday. My bad ;)